# Insert in to child table that have foreign key to an auto_increment column

Tags: mysql, sql

Schema is as shown below

```
           CREATE TABLE `country` (
           `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `country_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

            CREATE TABLE `state_table` (
              `id` int(11),
              `state_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
              `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
               PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`),
               CONSTRAINT `country_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) 
               REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE on update cascade
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='';
```

When I tried to insert data into both tables, data is inserting in to parent table but it is not inserting in to child table and error here is

```
Schema Creation Failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_2_3b712`.`state_table`, CONSTRAINT `country_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE):
```

As per my idea having country_id as auto_increment is creating problem.

I tried inserting like this

```
       INSERT INTO country (country_name) VALUES ('US of A');

       INSERT INTO state_table (state_name,id) VALUES
        ('Minnesota', 2),
        ('Arizona', 2);
```

Help me.

Answer (score 0):

The id that you are inserting must exist in country table and has to be a valid id of a country.

Propably there is no country with id=2.

You can get the inserted id using function **mysql_insert_id()**

So it'd look like this:

```
INSERT INTO country (country_name) VALUES ('US of A');

 INSERT INTO state_table (state_name,id) VALUES
  ('Minnesota', mysql_insert_id()),
  ('Arizona', mysql_insert_id());
```

Or even better you could assign this id to a variable and insert that.

```
INSERT INTO country (country_name) VALUES ('US of A');
$id = mysql_insert_id();

INSERT INTO state_table (state_name,id) VALUES
    ('Minnesota', $id),
    ('Arizona', $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `AUTO_INCREMENT`  to a foreign key constrained column?  Delete `AUTO_INCREMENT` from `country_id` column and try again.